# WSUS "Approve for Optional Install" not working as documented

Tags: powershell, wsus, .net

In [Microsoft's documentation on WSUS](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc708601(v=ws.10)#add-optional-installation-approvals-to-administrator-options), they explain that using the [IUpdate.ApproveForOptionalInstall](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/bb530767(v=vs.85)) enables an update to appear in Add/Remove programs (Install from network in Programs and Features), and it would not appear using Automatic Updates.

I have a couple of updates in WSUS 4.0 on Windows Server 2012 R2 that I had approved for optional install.  The updates were installed on machines running Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 via the Windows Update Agent.  This observed behavior seems to contradict the behavior that was documented.

Am I misunderstanding how this feature works?

Comment: I seem to recall that there is a Windows Update configuration option on pre-Windows 10 clients named something like "install optional updates automatically", have you checked that this is turned off?  There may be a corresponding group policy setting too.

Comment: Definitely check @HarryJohnston;s suggestion first.

Comment: The GUI setting I was thinking of is called "Give me recommended updates the same way I receive important updates" and the corresponding group policy setting is "Turn on recommended updates via Automatic Updates".  Probably not relevant, but worth checking.

Comment: My other question would be which updates you were attempting to deploy in this way, it probably only works for certain updates (if it works at all).

Comment: There's nothing in the documentation to suggest that it's for specific updates, but the updates on question are SQL Service Packs. The goal was to make them available from the WSUS server so the SQL owners could install it at their convenience without requiring it to be downloaded from the Internet.